# Can only the constructible sets be proven to exist in $ZF$ without benefit of extra assumptions?

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-philosophy, constructibility

I am interested in asking the following question:

> What sets can be proven to exist in $ZF$ without the benefit of extra assumptions? (Thanks to Toshiyasu Arai for inspiring me to ask this variation of his question from his slide presentation, ["Proof Theory for Set Theory"](http://www.helsinki.fi/lc2015/materials/slides_arai.pdf).)

I ask this question for the following reasons:

(i). The model of $ZF$ + $V$=$L$ is the smallest inner model of $ZF$ for any model of $ZF$, so it would seem that in every model of $ZF$, constructible sets exist, and in fact, every model $\mathfrak M$ of $ZF$ believes that its constructible sets form 'the' constructible universe $L$ (and in fact they do, relative to $\mathfrak M$).

(ii). Since every hereditarily finite set is constructible  (i.e., $V_{\omega}$ = $L_{\omega}$ so that for finite sets, $\mathscr P_{Def}$ = $\mathscr P$-- see Peter Koepke's  ["Simplified Constructibility Theory"](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Simplified_constructibility_theory_minicourse_Helsinki.pdf), for the distinction between $\mathscr P_{Def}$, the "predicative power-set operation" and $\mathscr P$, the "impredicative power-set operation"), one might reasonably abstract $\mathscr P_{Def}$ from the finite sets as the 'correct' means for generating 'the' cumulative hierarchy of sets of $ZF$ from $\emptyset$.

(iii) Since it is known that $V_{\omega}$ $\vDash$ $ZF$ $-$ *Infinity* (where in this case, $V_{\omega}$ and $L_{\omega}$ are, because *Infinity* is absent, proper classes), $L_{\omega}$ $\vDash$ $ZF$ $-$ *Infinity* so that one might use the following lemma of Michael Rathjen (from his paper, "A Proof-Theoretic Characterization of the Primitive Recursive Set Functions", *JSL* Vol. 53, No.3, Sept. 1992)(my comments will be in square brackets):

> Lemma 2.5.  For each $\Delta_0$-formula $\varphi$($x_1$,...,$x_n$) [in the language of set theory] with free variables among $x_1$,..., $x_n$ and each variable $x_j$, 1$\le$$j$$\le$$n$, there is a term $\mathscr F$ on $n$ arguments built from $\mathscr F_1$,...,$\mathscr F_{10}$ [Jech's version of the G$\ddot o$del operations from his *Millemium Edition*, Chapt. 13] so that
>
> $KP^{-}$ [Kripke-Platek set theory with Foundation replaced with Set Foundation] $\vdash$ $\mathscr F$($a$,$x_1$,...,$x_{j-1}$,$x_{j+1}$,...,$x_n$) = {$x_j$$\in$a| $\varphi$($x_1$,...,$x_n$)}
>
> Proof: All of the functions $\mathscr F_1$,..., $\mathscr F_{10}$ can be obtained on the basis of $KP^{-}$.  For instance, $KP^{-}$ is strong enough to prove the existence of the Cartesian product $a$ $\times$ $b$ of sets $a$ ans $b$ (see [Barwise:  *Admissible Sets ane Structures*, Chapt. I, Theprem 3.2]).  The result now follows from [Barwise, Ibid., Chapt II, Assumption 5.2(v)] because inspection of the proof of [Barwise, Ibid., Chapt. II, Assumption 5.2(v)] reveals that all of its steps can be done within $KP^{-}$.

Since $KP^{-}$ is a subtheory of $ZF$ $-$ *Infinity*, Lemma 2.5 holds for $ZF$ $-$ *Infinity* as well.  Not that if one chooses to add *Infinity* back to $ZF$ $-$ *Infinity* one has that the proper class $V_{\omega}$ (= $L_{\omega}$) is now a set and is also constructible.  Since $ZF$ $\vdash$ $\mathscr P_{L}$($\omega$) $\subseteq$ $\mathscr P$($\omega$) ($\mathscr P_{L}$ is the power-set for $L$ and is just $\mathscr P$($x$) $\cap$ $L$), Asaf's observation in his excellent answer (which is tantamount to saying that the constructibility or nonconstructibility of $\mathscr P$($\omega$) is independent of the axioms of set theory, i.e that though $\mathscr P$($\omega$) exists, it cannot be proven from the axioms of $ZF$ what subsets of $\omega$ are members of $\mathscr P$($\omega$)) seems to suggest (with the help of Rathjen's Lemma) that $ZF$ $\vdash$ $\mathscr P_{L}$($\omega$) = $\mathscr P$($\omega$) unless one adds the axiom "There exists a non-constructible set of integers".

Considering these reasons, I can refine the question as follows:

> Are the constructible sets the only sets that the axioms of $ZF$ alone can prove to exist?

Comment: If one can prove the existence of non constructive sets in ZF then one can prove in ZF that $V \neq L$ but this contradicts the consistency of ZF+V=L.

Comment: No! This was already explained to you in a previous version of this question: $\mathsf{ZF}+V=L$ is not a model, minimal or otherwise. It is a theory. You need to be more careful with these basic distinctions.

Comment: Also, I have the feeling your use of $\mathcal P_{\mathrm{Def}}(x)$ is somewhat non-standard. What precisely do you mean by this: $\mathcal P(x)\cap L[x]$, $\mathcal P(x)\cap L(x)$? $L_{\alpha+1}\cap \mathcal P(x)$ for $x\in L$ and $\alpha$ least such that $x\in L_\alpha$? Something else?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by your question? Are you asking whether, if $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that a formula defines a set, then the set is in $L$? (This is false.) Is it something more subtle?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo:  I have corrected the false basic distinction (hopefully).  Yes, it is something more subtle (I think).  Perhaps I should start with the question, "What sets can be proven to exist in $ZF$".  As is well known, the existence of a non-constructible set of integers ($0^{\sharp}$) can only be proven by assuming the existence of a measurable cardinal.   Though a model of $ZF$  + "There exists a measurable cardinal" is certainly a  model of $ZF$, it assumes something extra--the existence of a measurable cardinal.  What I want to know is, what sets can be proved to exist in $ZF$

Comment: (cont.) alone, without benefit of extra assumptions.  Does this help at all?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo:  I guess what I really want to ask is, Are the constructible sets the only sets that the axioms of $ZF$ alone can prove to exist?  Also,  $\mathscr P_{Def}$($x$) is just the predicative powerset  operation used to form the constructible hierarchy discussed in Koepke's mini-course preprint.

Comment: If you are asking about the ZF-provability of a specific statement $\varphi$ (such as "there are nonconstructible sets" or "all sets are constructible"), then please tell us what $\varphi$ is.  (For the two examples I gave, the answers are "no" and "no", assuming that ZF is consistent.)

Comment: @Goldstern:  $\varphi$ would be (in this case), "there are constructible sets".  What I am attempting to do is, by analogy to provably recursive sets in $PA$, define a syntactic notion of 'provably existent' definable in $ZF$ and show that the 'provably existent' sets are precisely the constructible sets.  Of course, one could assume the following axiom:  "All sets definable in $ZF$ exist", but since $0^{\sharp}$ is definable in $ZF$(?), one has as an easy consequence of $ZF$ + "All sets definable in $ZF$ exist", $V$ $\neq$ $L$.  But is equating existence with definability

Comment: (cont) conflation at its worst?  But if so, what sets exist?  If $ZF$ only proves that some sets exist, then $ZF$ would seem to me to be a very incomplete description of sets.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: Your axiom "all sets definable in ZF exist" does not make sense grammatically. Notice that you are trying to quantify over the same object with two different quantifiers, namely, "all" and "exist". How are you going to state this with a sentence in the language of set theory? An answer to this may help others understand what you mean by "sets proven to exist". (There are also issues regarding the notion "definable" because of Tarski's theorem on truth but let's ignore those for a second since there are notions of definability you can work with such as ordinal definable etc.)

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: If you provide us with a formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language of set theory which you think captures your notion of "the set $x$ being proven to exist", one can easily answer your question.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin 1. If you are asking whether "ZF proves 'there are constructible sets' ", then the question should be closed.  2. I cannot see a "syntactic notion of 'provably existent'" in your question.  If you are talking about a specific  syntactic notion, please write it down explicitly.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Regarding your comment that ZF is a "very incomplete description of sets":  That is true. (And, after 50 years of experience with forcing, rather obvious.)

Comment: @Goldstern and Burak:  Thank you for your comments.  Perhaps in order to  express the notion of 'exists' syntactically I would need to treat 'existence' as a predicate (there are logics in which 'exists' is a predicate, of course).  But as it stands, if 'exists' is a semantic notion, one could define 'exists' as 'being an element of a universe $M$ of a model $\mathfrak M$ of some theory $T$ ($ZF$ in this case).  So to say (for example) that '$0^{\sharp}$  exists' is to say that '$0^{\sharp}$ is an element of the universe $M$ of some model $\mathfrak M$ of $ZF$'.  There are, of course,

Comment: (cont) models of $ZF$ ($L$, for example) in which $0^{\sharp}$ does not exist and models of $ZF$ (where measurable cardinals also 'exist', say) in which $0^{\sharp}$ 'exists'.  I find it interesting that in every transitive model $\mathfrak M_{ZF}$ of $ZF$, $L$ is the smallest submodel of $\mathfrak M_{ZF}$.  If one restricts the class of models of $ZF$ to only the transitive models, one could possibly use G$\ddot o$del's completeness theorem (since every trasitive model of $ZF$ has $L$ as a submodel) to relate provability with the existence of constructible sets.  Am working on a suitable

Comment: (cont.) $\varphi$.

Comment: I am sorry.  To me it is "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @Goldstern:  I will try again to clarify.  I'm sorry that I have been 'clear as mud' thus far.  Question:  Since the properties of the  G$\ddot o$del operations are provable from $ZF$,  is the proper way to introduce them into $ZF$ is to add them as supplementary axioms to $ZF$?

Comment: (Cont.) or (better put) would the proper way to add the G$\ddot o$del operations into $ZF$ would be to add them to $ZF$ as supplementary axioms?

Comment: @Burak:  Here is the formula I wish to have $ZF$ prove:  ($\exists$$x$)($\exists$$\alpha$$\in$ $Ord$)($x$$\in$$L_{\alpha}$).  Also, please answer my question regarding the G$\ddot o$del operations.  Thanks.

Comment: That $\forall x \exists \alpha \in Ord \ x \in L_{\alpha}$ is literally the statement V=L and is not provable from ZFC, provided that it is consistent. That $\exists x \exists \alpha \in Ord \ x \in L_{\alpha}$ is trivially true as the empty set belongs to L.

Comment: @Burak:  So it would seem that to make that formula non-trivial, one might need to use the G$\ddot o$del operations to construct constructible sets from the empty set (or use $\mathscr P_{Def}$, of course).  For my part, I like the G$\ddot o$del operations, but to make things syntactically correct should I introduce them  as supplementary axioms (or can $\mathscr F_1$,..., $\mathscr F_{10}$ be derived as theorems from $ZF$)?  What to do, what to do....

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: I don't understand what you mean by "introducing operations as supplementary axioms". That does not really make sense. If you are talking about adding each sentence that specifies a property of a Gödel operation, ZF can already prove these, so you don't really have to add anything.

I don't really understand what you are after but my impression is that, once you are able to precisely state what you are thinking, you will end up getting the answers "No, ZFC cannot prove the existence of non-constructible sets. Yes, the constructible sets are the smallest inner model".

Comment: @Burak:  That is indeed helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\sf ZF$ can prove that $\mathcal P(\omega)$ exists, but it cannot prove whether or not every subset of $\omega$ is constructible. In other words, there are sets which provably exist, but it is not provable that they are constructible.

At the same time, as Mohammad writes, if one can prove that there exists a non-constructible set, then one disproves $V=L$, which means that $\sf ZF$ is already inconsistent to begin with.

---

Also, it is not true that $\mathcal P_{\rm def}$ is the "right" power set, since if you look at the $L$-hierarchy, you'll find that new subsets of $\omega$ are added in unboundedly many countable steps below $\omega_1$. So it is not right to say that $\mathcal P_{\rm def}(\omega)$ is "the right power set of $\omega$", if we can prove that the "second power set also adds subsets".

Comment: +1. To clarify your last paragraph for the OP with an example: note that every real in $L_{\omega+1}$ is arithmetic; however, $0^{(\omega)}$ is a non-arithmetic real which is in $L_{\omega+2}$.

Comment: @Thomas: That some sets exist. I don't understand your question. And frankly, I think that you don't understand your question either.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  What sets can $ZF$ prove exist?  And can $ZF$ prove some sets are constructible?  "Some sets exist" is obviously not a question.  I attempted to ask these questions, but in a different way.  Apparently (somehow) I didn't manage to delete all of it and this must have been the remnant.  Thanks for deleting this remnant for me--greatly appreciated.  By the way, is that all $ZF$ can prove--that some sets exist?

Comment: @Thomas: If ZF proves some set exists, then it proves that its power set exists; that its Hartogs and Lindenbaum numbers exist; that a bunch of other sets which have canonical definitions exist. The question has no "concrete" answer. Unlike PA, which has some nontrivial terms and can prove the existence of every natural number but not much more, ZF has only one relation symbol in the language of set theory so there are no non-trivial terms, and in particular there is no easy way to explain "which sets exist". Even more so, since "existence" is a semantic property, and provability is syntactic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Thanks for the clarification.  Are the G$\ddot o$del operations (out of which the constructible sets can be 'constructed') part of syntax or semantics (or both)?

Comment: @Thomas: They are definable class-functions. They can be seen as syntactic objects (as they should be), since they are classes (and not sets), and their properties are provable from ZF. The point is that "being constructible" is a property which, while syntactic, does not tell you much about whether certain sets satisfy this property of not (otherwise V=L would be provable or disprovable from ZF itself).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Actually, new subsets of $\omega$ are not added at every successor step.  Force with $\mathcal P(\omega_1)/\mathrm{NS}$, so that we get a generic elementary embedding $j : L \to M$ with critical point $\omega_1^L$.  $M$ is well-founded up to $\omega_2^L$.  Therefore, by absoluteness, it sees that there is a large gap after $\omega_1^L$ where no new subsets of $\omega$ are added.  By reflection this happens a lot below $\omega_1^L$.

Comment: @Monroe Or simply take a countable elementary substructure of a large fragment of the universe and collapse. The behavior of gaps is actually quite interesting.

Comment: @Andrés:  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Monroe: I knew that this is probably false the moment I re-read the answer. But I was waiting for someone to come along and correct me, because I wasn't 100% sure if it is in fact false or not. My point, of course, is that no countable step captures the entire power set of $\omega$.

Comment: @Asaf: It is somewhat counterintuitive.  You'd think that if $\alpha < \beta$ are countable and each satisfies a strong enough theory, then the set of Godel numbers of true sentences in $L_\alpha$ would be in $L_\beta \setminus L_\alpha$, but apparently not.  Of course by Tarski, this real cannot be definable in $L_\alpha$.

Comment: @Monroe: Wait, so how can there be a club of elementary submodels of $L_{\omega_1}$? Since obviously $L_{\omega_1}$ knows its own theory (it's just not aware that this is its own theory). I mean, it's a real, and at some point it will go into the $L$ hierarchy, and there will be a larger model which has that theory. So what you're saying can't be fully right, or I might be misunderstanding it.

Comment: @Asaf what did I say that's wrong?

Comment: @Monroe: I must have misunderstood you, then. Because if $L_\alpha\prec L_{\omega_1}$, then there is some $\beta$ large enough such that the theory of $L_\alpha$ lies in $L_\beta$. That was my point. I guess I just didn't fully understand yours.

Comment: I was just guessing that the idea that we always construct new reals might be based on the internal undefinability of truth, and saying this doesn't do it. My example was meant to say, certainly the theory of $L_\alpha$ is in $L_\beta$, but surprisingly it can be in $L_\alpha$ too.

Comment: @Monroe: Ah, okay. Then there is no clash between what we said... (Which unfortunately means that we cannot publish a paper about ZFC being inconsistent, well, at least not because of this argument... ;-))

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Do you believe that $\mathscr P_{Def}$ should be considered a 'power-set' at all, due to the observation given in your answer?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin What constitutes a powerset-like notion? There is certainly no model of ZF in which $\mathcal{P}_{def}$ is the **actual** powerset operation - indeed, ZF proves that as long as $A$ is infinite and $S$ is any set containing $A$, there will be subsets of $A$ which are not definable in $(S, \in)$ with parameters from $A\cup\{A\}$. And as usual ZF is massive overkill for this. The powerset operation in $L$ does indeedcome from a *transfinite iteration* of $\mathcal{P}_{def}$, but this is quite different from the idea that $\mathcal{P}_{def}=\mathcal{P}$, which is ZF-provably false.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  And yet it is defined as such--it is called the "predicative" power-set operation.  If one was able to define a predicative version of $ZF(C)$, would this version of the power-set operation be considerably different?  Also, would $\mathscr P_{Def}$ = $\mathscr P$ for $ZF$ $-$ _Infinity_?

Comment: @Thomas: Until you actually suggest a predicative power set operation, this is all moot. Yes, any operation which is a reasonable "power set" one would not be $\mathcal P_{\rm def}$. At the very least, it would have to capture *all* the subsets in one shot, otherwise it is not quite a power set operation. You seem to continuously ignore this, despite this being pointed out by several people. So I am going to reserve my energy and do something else, and I encourage the others to do so as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Please reread pp. 85-87 of Paul Cohen's   _Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis _   for (at least his) motivation as to the validity of defining $\mathscr  P_{Def}$ as a 'predicative power-set' (although Cohen actually writes, "...it was G$\ddot o$del's idea that if we iterate predicative constructions up to any ordinal the resulting sets could furnish an adequate model for $ZF$.")  If $\mathscr P_{Def}$ is not a 'power-set operation', what would you would define it as ?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin What we should call $\mathcal{P}_{def}$, or what the phrase "predicative powerset" means, is *irrelevant to the mathematics*; do you understand why $\mathcal{P}_{def}$ cannot be the same as $\mathcal{P}$ in any model of ZF (including one satisfying "V=L")? And even *this* doesn't really have anything to do with your question, which Asaf has (I also have, but more confusingly) thoroughly addressed. You are trying to form a big web of ideas, but you still don't understand the basics and wind up mixing several confusions. You should stick to your question, which has been answered.

Comment: The question is closed and has negative score, and there remains only one vote for deletion of the thread. At least superficially, the thread and the discussion in the comments don't seem to be of lasting value for readers, though I cannot really judge the contents. As your answer has positive score, would you object deletion? -- If yes, you might consider voting to reopen the question.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't think it has no value, it has some value. But I understand the deletion votes. I don't object to them, but I won't partake in the process. If any other set theorist feels that this should be deleted, so be it.

Answer (score 10):

There are several issues with this question; Andres has pointed out one glaring one, which is the conflation of *theories* and *models*. There is another issue, however, around what you are asking in the first place. Asaf has addressed one interpretation of your question, but there is another one:

> Suppose $\varphi$ is a formula such that ZF proves "there is exactly one $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds." Then does ZF prove "the unique $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds is constructible?"

*This matches more closely with e.g. Arai's theorem in his paper on lifting proof theory, where the focus is on when elements of definable, (ZF+V=L)-provably-nonempty sets enter $L$.*

The answer to *this* question is **very much no**, for trivial reasons. Take $\varphi(x)$ to be "either $x=0^\sharp$, or $x=\emptyset$ and $0^\sharp$ doesn't exist." ZF proves that there is exactly one $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds, but it is consistent with ZF that this $x$ is non-constructible.

Comment: Also, take $\varphi(x)$ to be "$x$ is the power set of $\omega$" works. Which is what I was driving at. And you don't even need to exceed the consistency strength of ZFC for that either. :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila Derp. Well, when you have indiscernibles, everything looks like . . . something that needs not to be discerned? I'unno.

Comment: I think the OP would benefit from thinking carefully about what (if anything) is meant by saying, of a set $S$ (as opposed to something like a definition of $S$), that "ZF proves that $S$ exists."

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Can $0^{\sharp}$ even be definable in $ZF$ (or $ZFC$) due to Tarski's result on the undefinability of truth (thanks to Todd Trimble for this observation)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Yes, it is definable - in fact, it's a $\Pi^1_2$ singleton. This is because it doesn't code truth in $V$, but rather in $L$, and it only exists if $V\not=L$ (and indeed if the theory of $V$ is quite different from that of $L$ - in particular, if $0^\sharp$ exists then the theory of $V$ contains "there is a measurable cardinal" while of course the theory of $L$ can't!). So there is no way that $0^\sharp$ exists *and* describes truth in $V$.

Comment: @Noah No, it contains "there is an $L$-measurable cardinal", or some such. But that is too informal. Thomas does not appear too clear yet on how weaker in consistency strength $0^\sharp$ is from a measurable, so that comment would probably increase confusion.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo:  Please define the notion of $L$-measurable cardinal.  Also, please provide the motivation(s) (mathematical and philisophical) for assuming the existence of $0^{\sharp}$ outright (as in $ZF(C)$ +  "$0^{\sharp}$ exists".

Comment: No, Thomas, that is not a reasonable question. The notion of $L$-measurable cardinal is nonstandard. It is a made-up word I used to refer to $L$-indiscernibles that would convey the same feeling that the informal ``there is a measurable cardinal'' in Noah's comment was meant to convey.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo:  Is the second part of my previous comment also unreasonable?

Comment: The second part of the comment is the unreasonable one. I answered the first part.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo (and Noah and Asaf): Hi guys. The crediting to me in Thomas's first comment comes from a discussion currently at meta about this question. I would be interested though in a discussion of this point about defining $0^\sharp$, which isn't directed just to Thomas but to the community. Or, what I'm *really* interested in seeing is an explicit example of Asaf's assertion "there are sets which provably exist, but it is not provable that they are constructible" -- because I got the sense that something like this is what Thomas wants. Thanks.

Comment: @Todd " what I'm *really* interested in seeing is an explicit example " That has been addressed explicitly several times: $x=\mathcal P(\omega)$ is an obvious example. It was pointed out at the beginning of the thread and in the answers. The issue about definability of $0^\sharp$ will probably be much more confusing than illuminating in this context. If you are interested, I suggest you ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @Todd: As Andrés points out, taking the power set of $\omega$ works as an example, which is something I have pointed out a ridiculous number of times on this page by now in my answer and in the various comment threads. I agree that the issue with $0^\#$ is probably more confusing than illuminating here without the technical understanding that would make the OP's question moot. The point in Noah's answer, I think, is that there are many examples of sets which have "robust definition" and consistently their existence outright refutes V=L. [...]

Comment: Oh jeez, my bad - AndrésE.Caicedo is totally right, I screwed up re: measurable cardinals. Forget I said that. I am tempted to delete this answer given how much confusion it has caused - the right answer is absolutely Asaf's. @ThomasBenjamin Asaf's is the answer you should be reading - although this one is also basically correct (I think my comment re: measurables is the only error - and that can be easily fixed, e.g. $0^\sharp$ implies "there is a nonconstructible set" which V=L clearly contradicts), it will be more confusing than helpful given your current understanding of the issues.

Comment: [...] for a simpler example one could take $x$ to be $\mathcal P(\alpha)$ for the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that L does not compute its power set correctly; or $0$ otherwise. In other words, either $x$ is empty, or it is the least non-constructible power set of an ordinal. Certainly ZF proves that $x$ exists and that it is a unique object in the universe. But $x$ is empty if and only if V=L is true. (This is a continuation to my previous comment addressed to @Todd...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila and Andrés: Oh sheesh. Yes, got it. Plain as day now.

Comment: The question is closed and has negative score, and there remains only one vote for deletion of the thread. At least superficially, the thread and the discussion in the comments don't seem to be of lasting value for readers, though I cannot really judge the contents. As your answer has positive score, would you object deletion? -- If yes, you might consider voting to reopen the question.